# how to tell javascript that the user enter a string in the prompt box and work with it in if statment

Tags: javascript

how to tell javascript that the user enter a string in the prompt box and work with it in an if statment ? If the user enters a string of letters I want it to alert "You did not enter a number", and if they entered a string if digits then continue with the logic.

```js
var userGess = prompt("guess a number");
var secretNumber = 7;
if (Number(userGess) > secretNumber) {
  alert("the number is to high")
} else if (Number(userGess) < secretNumber) {
  alert("the number is to low")
} else if (Number(userGess) == secretNumber) {
  alert("you are correct")
} else if (userGess == toString(userGess)) {
  alert("you didnt type a number")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isNaN(userGess)` to check if a given string `userGess` is non-numeric.

However, that returns false if `userGess` is empty string, so you have to explicitly check it. So your final condition becomes

```
userGess === "" || isNaN(userGess)
```

```js
var userGess = prompt("guess a number");
var secretNumber = 7;
if(userGess === "" || isNaN(userGess)) {
  alert("You didn't enter a number")
} else if (Number(userGess) > secretNumber) {
  alert("the number is to high")
} else if (Number(userGess) < secretNumber) {
  alert("the number is to low")
} else if (Number(userGess) == secretNumber) {
  alert("you are correct")
}
```